# "exceeding France’s rate in 2009 and reaching almost 60% in the end of period." Why not "exceeded" and "reached"?

Tags: participle-clauses

In this sentence why the ing form of the verb is used instead of past tense?

> Germany’s rate increased sharply throughout the period, exceeding France’s rate in 2009 and reaching almost 60% in the end of period.

Could we rewrite it in another way instead of ing form?

Comment: You could change to _exceeded_ and _reached_ if you like. It would mean the same.

Comment: @mdeway why the ing form is used? Is it continues form? If yes where is the “was” ?

Comment: "He stormed out of the house, slamming the door behind him." The door-slamming happened as part of the action of storming out. Germany exceeding France's rate was a part of the process of its rate increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clauses *exceeding France’s rate in 2009* and *reaching almost 60% in the end of period* are not "continuous" or any other tense.

They are non-finite clauses, used adverbially.

I can see how you might have confused them with "continuous tense", because these use the same "-ing" form of the verb, but it is different in construction and meaning.

You can often (but not always) replace them with *and* and a finite clause with the same tense as the parent clause. You can do so here: *and exceeded France's rate in 2009 and reached almost %60 in the end of period*.

By the way, *in the end of period* is either a mistake, or a sign that this was not written by a native English speaker. *At the end of the period* or *by the end of the period* would be normal, depending on the precise meaning intended.

Comment: Is this participle clause which added information about subject to avoid repetition?

Comment: "You can often (but not always) replace them with and and a finite clause with the same tense as the parent clause." Writing *and* and and distinguishing  *and* and and just with italics is confusing.

Comment: @Question: as I said, these could have been added as further finite clauses with "and".  Writing them as adverbial "-ing" clauses is a little more elegant, but has no singinificant difference in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

"Reaching" was used because it was in the process of reaching 60%, the ing form was used to indicate continuation at the time of writing.

If "reached" were used, it would mean it had stopped entirely.